# Unable to run standalone PyQGIS script with launch.bat file

Tags: pyqgis, batch, standalone, environment-variable

https://www.qgistutorials.com/ru/docs/running_qgis_jobs.html

I want to run a script in a file called `my_plugin.py`.
The script is:

```
print ('Hello QGIS!')
```

The path for the script is:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\my_plugin.py
```

if I open my command prompt and I do:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39>python my_plugin.py
```

***But I want one that works with a bat file!!***

In the tutorial, it is written in page 14 to set the environment in the bat file as follows:

```
REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder 
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64 SET QGISNAME=qgis 
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME% set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS% 
REM Gdal Setup set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\share\gdal\ 
REM Python Setup
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH% 
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27 
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
    
REM Launch python job 
python c:\Users\Ujaval\Desktop\download_and_clean.py 
pause
```

Obviously, I have adapted the suggested environments in the tutorial intuitively with my personal path created with OSGEOW4 QGIS 3.22.14 and Python39. I've written a file launch.txt with the following environment variables:

```
REM Change OSGEO4W_ROOT to point to the base install folder
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
SET QGISNAME=qgis-ltr
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
REM Gdal Setup
set GDAL_DATA=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\gdal\share\gdal\
REM Python Setup
set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

REM Launch python job
python C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\my_plugin.py
pause
```

After that, I change the extension of the file launch.txt to launch.bat.

I double click the launch.bat file. It runs but it stops before writing

> Hello QGIS!

Here is the image after running the launch.bat file. I also have checked and every path is ok redirecting to an existing path, but it does not work.
[image: cmd terminal screenshot]

What do I have to do to solve this issue with the bat file?

**EDIT 26.12.2022**
Now it works.

I found errors or things that in my case prevent obtaining the result.

1.I had to set my environment variable in Environment Variables in the properties: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html

2.here is the content of my launch.bat file. It is deprived of all environment variable and there is only the final part.

```
ECHO OFF
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe C:\Users\Simone\OneDrive\Desktop\my_plugin.py
PAUSE
```

this final part is different of my old reference that had written only python.....pause instead of ECHO OFF....pause:

```
REM Launch python job
python c:\Users\Ujaval\Desktop\download_and_clean.py
pause
```

3. my reference had written print 'Hello QGIS!'instead of print ('Hello QGIS!')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for Windows, that QGIS tutorial makes a lot more work out of running a QGIS Python script from a batch file than is necessary.  Why create a batch file to set all the environment variables when QGIS has already done the work with `qgis_process-qgis.bat`?  I would argue it is better to rely on QGIS setting the Windows environment variables than trying to manually set them.

Contents of `launch.bat`:

```
rem Call qgis_process-qgis.bat file to set QGIS Windows environment variables
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.0\bin\qgis_process-qgis.bat"

rem Append QGIS Python Plugins directory to PYTHONPATH
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%/python/plugins

rem Launch Python job
python c:\Users\Ujaval\Desktop\download_and_clean.py

rem Pause Windows batch job
pause
```

You will have to modify the path based on the QGIS install on your local machine.

**UPDATE**:  I updated the code above to reflect the fact that calling `o4w_env.bat` sets everything up to use the OSGeo4W bundled Python interpreter, but it doesn't set everything up to use `qgis` Python package(s).  Calling `qgis_process-qgis.bat` calls `o4w_env.bat`, but it adds settings to use `qgis` Python packages.  *However*, that does not address the matter of QGIS Python plugins, so the plugin directory needs to be appended to the `PYTHONPATH` environment setting.

Comment: @simone100 if you have a working solution, please add it as an additional answer, rather than in a comment. It makes things clearer for future readers.